# Could we always use the list type as the function parameter when the tuple type parameter is expected?

Tags: python, list, tensorflow, tuples

I have been studying the Tensorflow API written in Python. I have two questions.

**1. Can we always use a list type as a function parameter when a tuple is expected?**

If we look at the official API definition about the `tf.placeholder` and its examples (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder), we see that the second parameter of this function is the "shape". In the example code, we can see that a tuple is used to provide the shape information as a parameter as shown below.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1024, 1024))
```

However, in the official tutorial page (https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners), the example uses the **list** as the shape rather than using the tuple as shown below.

```
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
```

I know that there are some differences between list and tuple such as being immutable vs mutable.

If the list supports all the functionality of a tuple, then could we always use the list instead of the tuple safely as a function parameter? And is it recommended?

**2. What's the meaning of [None, 10] in the above example code?**

In the above example code, [None, 10] is used. Are such expressions normally used? If so, then is "None" also considered as a kind of number?

Comment: Strictly speaking, no. `def foo(mytuple): return {mytuple}; foo([])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost everything which you can do on `tuple` you can do on list too. However the vice-versa is not true because `tuple` are immutable whereas `list` are mutable.

But there's exception. Since tuple is immutable:

- it can be used as a key in a dictionary.
- used in a `set`.

Lists are intended to be homogeneous sequences, while tuples are heterogeneous data structures. Also, `tuple` are little better in terms of performance.

From the [Python's  Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) document:

> Though tuples may seem similar to lists, they are often used in different situations and for different purposes. Tuples are immutable, and usually contain a heterogeneous sequence of elements that are accessed via unpacking (see later in this section) or indexing (or even by attribute in the case of namedtuples).

---

So the answer to your question:

> Can we always use a list type as a function parameter when a tuple is expected?

*You may use `list` instead of `tuple` in most of the cases, but not always.* But you need not to worry much about this, as Python will remind you when your usage of `list` may go wrong. Below is the error which you'll receive on doing so:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

For example:

```
>>> set([1, [1, 2]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

>>> {[1, 2]: 1}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem related to TensorFlow.

Answer (score 1):

As MoinuddinQuadri noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48038899/7505395 for *this usage* you can interchange a 2 element `list` for a `tuple`.

To answer your **2nd** question:

According to the documentation you linked, `[None,784]` in the context of `shape` means that one dimension is unlimited, one is fixed to 784:

https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners#implementing_the_regression

> `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])`
>
> `x` isn't a specific value. It's a `placeholder`, a value that we'll input when we ask TensorFlow to run a computation. We want to be able to input any number of MNIST images, each flattened into a 784-dimensional vector. We represent this as a 2-D tensor of floating-point numbers, with a `shape [None, 784]`.
>
> (Here `None` means that a dimension can be of any length.)

Answer (score 1):

"Can we always use a list type as a function parameter when a tuple is expected?"

No. Aside from other reasons, the function may check the type.

```
>>> issubclass(ZeroDivisionError, (Exception,))
True
>>> issubclass(ZeroDivisionError, [Exception,])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    issubclass(ZeroDivisionError, [Exception,])
TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes
```

There are also a couple of places where Python syntax requires a tuple, as in except clauses.

```
>>> try: 1/0
except (Exception,) as e: print(e)

division by zero
>>> try: 1/0
except [Exception] as e: print(e)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    try: 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 2, in <module>
    except [Exception] as e: print(e)
TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```